# Moments of a barbell

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics, moment

For a barbell with
1. heavier weights near the centre

2. heavier weights near the end (invert the order of the weights in the picture below)

Will the barbell with heavier weights near the end be harder to lift since the moments (force * distance) are higher? Or will the 2 sides somehow balance each other without increase your effort needed to lift both sides?

[image]

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifting is associated with mass. As long as the total mass in the same, lifting it does not require any additional effort.

However, rotating it may become different. So if you are reaaaally good at lifting it symmetrically nothing changes. Otherwise something may change as you have to "overcome" its tendency to rotate.

Suppose the following barbells are of length $2L$.

Barbell 1 has two masses $m$ at distance $L$ from the center and two masses $M$ at distance $L-a$ from the center (with $M>m$, and $a\ll L$) so it is a "normal" barbell, the one in the picture.

Barbell 2 has two masses $M$ at an opposite distance $L$ from the center and two masses $m$ at distance $L-a$ from the center (with $M>m$, and $a\ll L$) so it is an inverted barbell.

What regolates the tendecy to rotate is the moment of inertia. Think of it as the equivalent of mass as far as rotations are concerned.
The first one has (with respect to the center):
$$I_1=2mL^2+2M(L-a)^2=2mL^2+2ML^2+2Ma^2-4MLa$$

the second one

$$I_2=2ML^2+2m(L-a)^2=2ML^2+2mL^2+2ma^2-4mLa$$
so that
$$I_2-I_1=4(M-m)La-2(M-m)a^2=2(M-m)(2La-a^2)>0$$ (since $M>m$ and $La>a^2$).
meaning that $I_1<I_2$ so the first barbell is easier to handle having a smaller moment.

The first one is also the normal one so it makes sense that is designed to be easier to handle!

Notice also that in the limit $L, a\rightarrow 0$ (point mass) there is no moment of inertia so rotations are not involved.

Moreover, notice that the length of the barbell and the distance $a$ are both relevant.

Comment: Did u accidentally swap the definition of barbell 1 and 2? I was actually referring barbell 1 (heavier weights nearer to the centre) as the one in picture.
Since lifting it perfectly symmetrical is practically infeasible, placing heavier weights nearer to centre will be beneficial in reducing the imbalance in effort needed on one side of the shoulder (assuming you are doing squats)?

Comment: I agree that there is a bit of confusion in my answer.
Barbell 1 is the inverted one (small masses farther from the center than big ones)
Barbell 2 is the normal one and has a smaller moment so its easier to rotate.

Comment: I edited so it's clearer and follows your definition.